# Linux machine not supporting many Unix commands

Tags: linux, shell, command

I don't know what happened to this Linux machine, but now it is not recognizing many Unix commands anymore

```
~ # uname -a
Linux mpc8306som 2.6.34.10-WR4.3.0.0_standard #9 PREEMPT Mon Jun 17 10:55:18 CST 2013 ppc GNU/Linux
~ # echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin
~ # cal
  May 2014
Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa
             1  2  3
 4  5  6  7  8  9 10
11 12 13 14 15 16 17
18 19 20 21 22 23 24
25 26 27 28 29 30 31

~ # which
-sh: which: not found
~ # whereis
-sh: whereis: not found
~ # find / -iname "whereis*" -print
~ # find / -iname "which*" -print
~ # apt-get
-sh: apt-get: not found
~ # yum
-sh: yum: not found
```

How can I fix these problems?

---

This is a [Wind River Linux](http://www.windriver.com/products/linux.html) system — their version 4.3 small (standard).

Comment: What distribution is it? http://superuser.com/a/11020/96285

Comment: Reinstall?  Are the programs there, anywhere (`/usr/local/bin` is missing from your PATH, perhaps)? Ubuntu or Debian or a.n.other?  Have you switched shells by accident?  When was the machine last working?  Who could have changed it?  If it was you, what did you do?  You might find that ServerFault or perhaps SuperUser or Ask Ubuntu or another site is more appropriate -- there isn't much programming involved in this.

Comment: @MartinKonecny : thanks for your prompt response. All these commands returned "No such file or directory" but cat /proc/sys/kernel/osrelease returned "2.6.34.10-WR4.3.0.0_standard"

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: thanks for your response. There is nothing in my /usr/local/bin ~ # ls -la /usr/local/bin
total 4
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root          1024 Sep  3  2012 .
drwxr-xr-x   12 root     root          1024 Jun 24  2013 ..
~ #. Reinstalling is not an option for now because there are many up and running services on this machine. I don't know its history, it was given to me and I need to install other new services on it, but it's not taking any commands

Comment: Any `/etc/*release` files might give you a better idea of what distribution you're using, but a quick Google search on your `osrelease` indicates it's probably [Wind River Linux](http://www.windriver.com/products/linux.html). Looks like it's targeted for embedded systems, which means a lot of stuff is likely to be missing. I find that the built-in `type` command does most of what `which` and `whereis` do.

Comment: @KeithThompson: thanks for your response. Indeed, it's a Wind River Linux glibc_small (standard) 4.3. I used "which" and "whereis" as examples, but I need support for "apt-get" or "yum" to install new packages. How can I install new packages on this machine?

Comment: Sounds like you'll need to go to the Wind River site to get the basic installers (or you'll find the installer is `rpm` instead of `yum` or `apt-get`, or something).  The installer will have to be isntalled semi-manually; once it is installed, you can run it to get the others.  But you need to go though its support channels; there won't be general help here.  It sounds like a quite specialized distribution of Linux; it will probably have its own quite specialized rules and mechanisms.

Comment: @rh4games: I don't know; I've never used Wind River Linux. Different Linux systems use different packaging systems -- and the embedded Linux systems I work on don't have a package management system at all. I expect there's ample documentation on Wind River's site, or as Jonathan suggests you can go through their support channels. If that doesn't help, then http://serverfault.com/ or http://unix.stackexchange.com/ would be a better place to ask.

Comment: As far as I can tell, Wind River is RPM based, so try that; but the list of available packages is extremely limited.

Comment: @tripleee: thanks for your help. RPM is not supported either, it returns "-sh: rpm: not found". Only "install" seems to be supported "~ # install
BusyBox v1.20.2 (2013-05-15 14:44:14 CST) multi-call binary.

Usage: install [-cdDsp] [-o USER] [-g GRP] [-m MODE] [SOURCE]... DEST

Copy files and set attributes

        -c      Just copy (default)
        -d      Create directories
        -D      Create leading target directories
        -s      Strip symbol table
        -p      Preserve date
        -o USER Set ownership
        -g GRP  Set group ownership
        -m MODE Set permissions

~ #"

Comment: `install` on the other hand *is* a "Unix command"; it is basically a variant of the `cp` command from GNU Coreutils. Not what you are looking for.

Comment: The docs I looked at (some ols PDF; sorry, lost the link already) talked about "source RPM" so that would suggest that you are expected to compile what you need yourself.

Answer (score -1):

Reinstall?

Unless it is really required, I try not to fix broken machines too long. I make it easy to deploy new ones and recycle when shit hits the fan...

But then I also usually run virtualized systems and snapshot working setups.

Comment: It seems to be an embedded system, which means that it's likely not to have a lot of the stuff you'd expect on desktop or server systems. It's probably not broken, just limited, and reinstalling is unlikely to help.

Comment: Agreed. Those are not "Unix commands", anyway, although they are common on many Linux distros.